How to close the prompt box in an extension?
I click a submit button on a form on a web page but after long time the submission fails due to server error(request timed out). Then, when I refresh the page, a prompt box shows up saying "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier." and asking me to click a button to resend or cancel. Worse is if I refresh the page again, the same prompt box shows up and seems to be overlapped on the previous one(the previous one seems not closed). I wonder if I can detect and close this kind of prompt boxes in a content script or background script automatically?
(When the prompt box shows up, I cannot even right-click on the web page to inspect the element so I don't know what this prompt box exactly is.)

Extensions can't bypass such dialogs. You can suggest it in bugzilla or WECG if it wasn't already suggested.

@woxxom If content script/background cannot bypass such dialogs, can they detect them and how?

There's probably no workaround because it's a modal that pauses the entire JS.

@woxxom But it only stops running the JS in one TAB, right? So, theoretically, the background script still runs and can detect the existence of such a dialog in a tab.

No, the problem is that the tab can't answer.
